# Can Azure MFA work with on-prem MS AD users?

Tags: multi-factor-authentication

We have an On Prem Windows AD, and it is one-way sync'd with our AZURE AD. I want to enable AZURE MFA on some of our on-prem AD Users. Can this work? And if so, what do I need to do to get it working. I enabled it on the users in the Azure portal but it does not prompt the on-prem users for MFA.
MFA works fine for the Azure AD user accounts but I need to get it turned on for our on-prem users that are AZ Connect sync'd to our AZURE Tenant as well.